# Dynamically manage sub image dnd in a canvas

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, svg

I work with java,svg canvas, svg files and with eclipse.

My canvas manage the dnd of files. The dnd of a basic svg file  in the current document is ok. We need to copy the contents of the dropped file in the current document.

What I want to do now is to dnd a file which will be incorporate as a sub image in the current document.

Situation :
I have a A.svg file  and I want to use it as a subimage in a B.svg file.
I dnd the A.svg file in the B.svg document.

What happens :
A tag "image" is created in the tag "defs" of the B.svg file and a "use" tag is created to display the referenced sub image.

Here is my B.svg document before the dnd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="91"  contentStyleType="text/css" viewBox="0 0 91 159" height="159" version="1.0">
    <defs/>
</svg>
```

And here it is after the dnd of my sub image A.svg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="91"  contentStyleType="text/css" viewBox="0 0 91 159" height="159" version="1.0">
    <defs>
        <g id="A">
            <image width="91" xlink:href="A.svg" xlink:type="simple" xlink:actuate="onLoad" height="159" xlink:show="embed"/>
        </g>
    <defs/>
    <use xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 485 134)" xlink:href="#A"/>
</svg>
```

I dynamically modify the svg dom and I do a refresh of the canvas content after the dnd.
My problem is even with this refresh after I droped the sub image, the content is not updated. I selectionable point appears at the coordinates 0,0, but that is all.

But if I CLOSED and RE OPEN the canvas, then the sub image is well display.

I would like to get the same result but without needed to close and re open the svg file.

Tell me if you need more information or if I am not clear enough.

Comment: After the dnd, I modify the dom svg by accessing the different nodes, and I add the sub image part. I think it is not refreshing dynamically because of the attribute " xlink:actuate="onLoad" " but I don't know how to modify it or remove it...